# The Google Play services resources were not found when running InterstitialAd

Tags: java, android, admob

I am trying to use Google AdMob to display InterstitialAd but I have a problem with Google services. After I run my app on device I receive the following message:

> The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project
>   configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

This is my code:

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(getActivity()); 
interstitial.setAdUnitId("id");
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) { 
        interstitial.show(); 
    } 
}
```

What could be a problem? Thanks!

Comment: From: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ *Add and reference the Google Play services library project. See the Android instructions for how to set up the Google Play services SDK*. Include it to your project.

Comment: @AlexBcn, I've done that but this error still displays.

Comment: Sometimes, this log is benign. Are you still seeing Ads? Also, do you see onAdLoaded() in Logs? Or can you share the other logs with Tag "Ads" here?